# How to inline a XML string (suppress all unnecessary characters) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, regex, xml, string

I have a string describing a XML object, containing line-breaks and spaces, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<play>
  <scenario>
    <author>Arthur Drake</author>
    <title> ...til I get there</title>
  </scenario>
</play>
```

And I'd like to convert it like so all unnecessary characters are removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><play><scenario><author>Arthur Drake</author><title> ...til I get there</title></scenario></play>
```

Note that the whitespaces *inside* the nodes should be left untouched.

What is the best solution to do so in Node.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should give you the result you're looking for:

```js
let xml = 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<play>
<scenario>
  <author>Arthur Drake</author>
  <title> ...til I get there</title>
</scenario>
</play>`;

console.log('Initial xml:', xml);

function trimXml(xml) {
    return xml.replace(/>\s+</g, "><");
}

console.log('\nTrimmed xml:', trimXml(xml));
```